# Lesser known VS 2010 extensions that provide great all purpose functionality?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What VS 2010 extensions do you recommend for improving all purpose development?
I've been having a look through the ones on [MSDN](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/), started to wonder if there were any that provide some great/unique features but haven't really got popular for some reason? :)

Also wondering if there are any other repositories for VS extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StructureAdornment](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/203f22f4-3e9f-4dbb-befc-f2606835834e) and [VSCommands 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf) are really usefull.

Answer (score 2):

A Vim plugin, like ViEmu or VsVim, is the only way to code in VS.

Comment: Using VsVim here. Is ViEmu better?

Comment: No idea, but you need at least a Vim-based plugin.

Comment: I added in VsVim to my answer.

Comment: I very much eager to know what is the functionality of ViEmu

Comment: @Avatar They provide Vi-like keybindings for VS. Have you ever used Vi? Its very different, but I believe its the fastest way to edit.

Comment: @mathepic nope. But, got the add-in going to try it soon. Thanks for that :)

Comment: @Avatar I hope you like it, but it may not be for you. Its fast editing, but only once you get used to it.

Answer (score 2):

I do like '[DevColor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7dbae8b3-5812-490e-913e-7bfe17f47f1d)' when working with css.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Visual Nunit 2010
2) Regex Editor
3) Spell Checker
4) yUML

are few good ones.